# What is main difference between hyperledge Fabric 0.6、1.0 and 1.1 version?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What is the main goal to modify fabric source code from 0.6 version to 1.1?
what is the most important change logs ? Architecture? Please describe or provide some important reference!

Answer (score 1):

Each release is accompanied by changelog entries linking to the JIRA issues closed (representing every commit), and we also publish release notes in two places: on the GitHub repositories ([fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases), [fabric-ca](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/releases), [fabric-sdk-node](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/releases), [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/releases), [fabric-chaincode-node](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/releases)) and in the [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/releases.html) that uplevel to a more human accessible description of the major new features or changes.

tl;dr: v0.6 -> v1.0.0 was a major re-architecture of the consensus model and added support for channels. v1.1.0 -> v1.1.0 is a series of performance and scale improvements, added support for Javascript (Node.js) chaincode, added support for CouchDB and attribute based access control and a few other features, but is forward compatible with v1.0.x releases and can be upgraded in place.

Comment: Thank for your answer.Could you make some important conclusion about 0.6  1.0 1.1? We can not grab the importance from the change log?

Comment: And could you provide a important time sequence chart from fabric versions change ?Thank you

Comment: v0.6 was released in June 2016. v1.0.0 was released in July 2017. v1.1.0 will be released in 1Q2018 by our best estimates. We expect to continue the practice of releasing patch releases monthly and are planning for roughly quarterly releases from here on out.